# HDD doesn't recognize hdparm -S flag

Tags: hdparm

My WD6400AAKS is attached to a Raspberry by USB. It is contained in an external USB-case with access LED. It works fine on hdparm -y and spins down. If you do an ls on that drive, it spins up. So far so good.
Unfortunately it doesn't recognize -S. Tried -S 1, -S 12. hdparm returns correctly with no error, but drive won't spin down, though no access is indicated by LED.
Any idea?

Comment: You wrote "Tried -S1… hdparm returns **correctly**" Do you mean it ouput "*setting standby to 1 (5 seconds)*" ?

Comment: Yes, exactly that

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the `Advanced Power Management Feature` to `127`.

`hdparm` manpages:

```
-B     Get/set  Advanced  Power  Management feature, if the drive supports it. A low value
       means aggressive power management  and  a  high  value  means  better  performance.
       Possible  settings  range  from  values 1 through 127 (which permit spin-down), and
       values 128 through 254 (which do not permit  spin-down).   The  highest  degree  of
       power  management  is attained with a setting of 1, and the highest I/O performance
       with a setting of 254.  A value of 255  tells  hdparm  to  disable  Advanced  Power
       Management  altogether  on the drive (not all drives support disabling it, but most
       do).
```

By setting the Advanced Power Management Feature to a value lower than 128, you allow the drive to spin down. The `-S parameter` is used to set the timeout of the idle time required, but the firmware may not obey that parameter if the Advanced Power Management Feature is off, for example.

Comment: Doesn't work for me:
$ sudo hdparm -B127 /dev/sda
/dev/sda:
 setting Advanced Power Management level to 0x7f (127)
 HDIO_DRIVE_CMD failed: Invalid argument
 APM_level = not supported

I'm using -y which spins down the drive sucessfully, but something wakes it up again some minutes later and I don't know how to figure out, what wakes up the drive.

Comment: Seems like the ARM is not supported by your drive, @fbstov. In that case, try `hd-idle`, which can be installed on various distributions using their package manager. It'll spin down your drive just as the -S option would do, and it was the second solution I've tried. Worked for me very well, and since -y works for you, I guess `hd-idle` works as well.